# grunt-contrib-concat: specify last file to be concatenated?

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-concat, load-order

I'm using grunt-contrib-concat to concatenate all my custom JS files together, and wrap them with an IIFE. I'm running into some load order issues ( namely, my init file is executing before some modules, causing undefined errors ). I want to specify `init.js` should be LAST in the concat order, but I don't want to specify the order for all the other JS files as well, just that this specific one goes last.

Here is the current config of my concat:

```
/**
 * Set project info
 */
project: {
  src: 'src',
  app: 'app',
  assets: '<%= project.app %>/assets',
  css: [
    '<%= project.src %>/scss/style.scss'
  ],
  js: [
    '<%= project.src %>/js/*.js'
  ]
},

concat: {
  dev: {
    files: {
      '<%= project.assets %>/js/scripts.min.js': '<%= project.js %>'
    }
  },
  options: {
    stripBanners: true,
    nonull: true,
    banner: ';(function($, window, document, undefined){ \n "use strict";',
    footer: '}(jQuery, window, document));'
  }
},
```

How do I specify a last file to be concatenated **without adding an extra grunt module to my project**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by concatenating all files **but** `init.js`, and then concatenating the result with `init.js`, using the array syntax that maintains order:

```
concat: {
    dev1: {
        dest: '<tmp>/concat1.js',
        src: ['<all your js>', '!init.js']
    },
    devFinal: {
        options: {
            stripBanners: true,
            nonull: true,
            banner: ';(function($, window, document, undefined){ \n "use strict";',
            footer: '}(jQuery, window, document));'
        },
        files: {
            dest: 'scripts.min.js',
            src: ['<tmp>/concat1.js', 'init.js']
        },
    },
}
```

And then call both targets in succession:

```
grunt.registerTask('myConcat', ['concat:dev1', 'concat:devFinal']);
```

Comment: I'm away from my project currently so unable to test, but would this cause both tasks to be wrapped in their own IIFE (the banner/footer in the options)? Or would only the output of devFinal? I need the later.

Comment: if you move your options block under the second target, it should only apply to it. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Hi -- worked great once I changed the structure of the files object -- must be my concat version but I had to do ie `files: { 'dest-file-name.js': ['file1.js', 'file2.js' 'etc..'] }`